# Looking for a way to let the end user know all formulas have completed computation after pasting new data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am working on an automated dashboard, where a report in a certain format is just pasted into a certain section of the workbook and all the formulas, which are dynamic, start processing immediately to populate the final analysis dashboard.

Now, since sometimes the data can be huge, it takes a lot of time for the processors to finish computation.

I request help in understanding if there's a possibility of the following:

- I wish to let the end-user know that all formulas are done computing
  and the data dashboard is good to look at now.
- Can this be done using a formula that only computes in the end, which
  i can then manipulate to show "DONE" or something similar?

Any help would be great.
Thanks.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're trying to do....  are you asking if you can make a cell say "calculating" when Excel is calculating and change to "done" when Excel's finished calculating? ..because Excel already does *that*.  Or perhaps a progress bar that shows the progress of your custom tasks?  That's easy to add to existing VBA code.  **Are you thinking of something like one of these :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6khk.png   ?**

Comment: Yes, I know excel already does that in the status bar, but the issue is, my end-user isn't very excel friendly, hence wont look at the status bar.

They'd need something definitive to show "All calculations are done - Data is ready to use" to go ahead, else they'll end up picking up data still under computation.